# Select table size and row counts for specific schema

Tags: postgresql

I need to have a query that would give me the information for each table in specific `schema`. The information would be the `size of the table (best in Mb)` and also the `row counts`. I prepared some query as below but not sure if the result is in `megabytes`. Moreover i do not know how to get the `row counts` from  `information_schema.tables`. Can somebody help?

This is my current query:

```
select table_name, pg_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name)) 
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'myschema'
order by 2;
```

**EDIT:**

By this i can get row counts nevertheless do not know how to filter based `on` specific schema and how to add table size in Mb to it.

```
  select nspname as schema, relname as tablename, 
  reltuples as rowcounts
  from pg_class c JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
   ON n.oid = c.relnamespace where relkind='r'
   and relname like 't%'
   order by nspname, reltuples desc;
```

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/278977 is this helpful?

Comment: @AdilKhalil See my EDIT. By the query u provided i can get row counts nevertheless how to add to them table size in mb and filter based on specific schema?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of the table in megabytes using the `pg_relation_size` function. By default the function will return the result in bytes, but you can convert the result to megabytes. Also, to filter by a specific scheme, use the `table_schema` entry from `information_schema.tables`.

```
SELECT 
   table_name,
   (pg_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name)) / 1024 /1024) size,
   reltuples as rowcounts FROM information_schema.tables ist
left join pg_class pc on pc.relname = ist.table_name
   WHERE table_schema = 'public'
```

Demo in [sql<>daddy.io](https://sqldaddy.io/9c3a0895)